# How do I use a list of compressed files for a lazy dataframe in Polars?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I was wondering if it is possible to read a folder with compressed CSV/JSONL files as a lazy dataframe in Polars. I see `scan_csv` in Pandas API but no sign of supporting compressed files. (Originally this appeared when [trying out nushell](https://github.com/tvbeat/issues/issues/7856#issuecomment-1721283694))

Comment: I want to say that `CsvReader` and/or `LazyCsvReader` can do this “for free” if you enable features `decompress` or `decompress-fast` (not sure what the difference is)

Comment: I can't find anything like that in rustdocs, would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: I didn't find any docs, I just ctrl-F‘d “compress” on its docs.rs page and went from there

Comment: Thanks, that's at least something (I need zstd and that option adds support for (g)zip)